# Прореживание полилинии

Tags: алгоритм, математика, геометрия

Какие есть хорошие алгоритмы для прореживания замкнутой полилинии?

На входе есть **замкнутая** ломаная, хочется проредить её, сохранив "характерные особенности". Например, если ломаная визуально имеет резкую петельку, не хочется её потерять.

Хотелось бы список алгоритмов, заточенных под решение такой (или схожей) задачи. Погуглив удалось найти алгоритмы, которые заточены под незамкнутую кривую, плюс там обычно ставится требование попадание в некую эпсилон окрестность исходной кривой (к примеру - алгоритм Рамера-Дугласа-Пекера), это не совсем то, что нужно (хотя, возможно, я просто недопонял алгоритмы), потому что они как раз смазывают резкие повороты.

Я думал пробовать делать так - разделить полилинию на несколько дуг, и каждую прореживать алгоритмом РДП (или любым другим), но такой метод во-первых зависит от исходного разбиения на дуги, ну и во-вторых он по-прежнему направлен на эпсилон-близость, а хочется чтобы он уделял высокую важность ещё и поворотам.

С точки зрения теории, тутскорее всего нужно завести какую-то целевую функцию, которая будет во-первых учитывать эпсилон-близость, и во-вторых близость по поворотам (первая производная), с двумя коэффициентами цены, скорее всего это даст хороший результат (после подбора коэффициентов). Возможно, такой алгоритм уже есть (или строится из классических), не хотелось бы изобретать велосипед...

Answer (score 0):

Нужен пример этой ломаной и ее преобразования в кривую  с "сохранением особенностей". Неясен критерий по которому вы хотите сохранять особенности. Из наиболее простых вариантов - дробите каждый отрезок пополам. две половинки отрезков, касающихся в вершине исходной ломаной, заменяете кривой Безье. Получите гладкую замкнутую кривую. Там можно кучу дополнительных "если" понапридумывать для красоты результата. Например, можно длинные ребра пилить не пополам, а сглаживать некоторые куски по краям, оставляя центральную часть прямой. Слишком короткие ребра можно сглаживать с двумя соседними. И т.д. и т.п.